# AWS Cognito InitiateAuth through Lambda function results into error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am writing a Lambda function in Go to authenticate a user, the AccessToken/IdToken I want to use for subsequent API calls.

When I execute the Go code from a standalone program, it works, the InitiateAuth was successful.

When I tried to use the same code from the lambda function, I get an error  NotAuthorizedException: Unable to verify secret hash for client .......

Here is the code snippet I am using

```
func AuthenticateUser(userName string, passWord string) (*cognitoidentityprovider.InitiateAuthOutput, error) {

    username := aws.String(userName)
    password := aws.String(passWord)
    clientID := aws.String(constants.COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID)

    params := &cognitoidentityprovider.InitiateAuthInput{
        AuthFlow: aws.String("USER_PASSWORD_AUTH"),
        AuthParameters: map[string]*string{
            "USERNAME": username,
            "PASSWORD": password,
        },
        ClientId: clientID,
    }

    authResponse, authError := cognitoClient.InitiateAuth(params)
    if authError != nil {

        fmt.Println("Error = ", authError)
        return nil, authError
    }

    fmt.Println(authResponse)
    fmt.Println(*authResponse.Session)

    return authResponse, nil
}
```

I have given sufficient permissions to the lambda user
- cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser
- cognito-idp:AdminDeleteUser
- cognito-idp:InitiateAuth
- cognito-idp:ChangePassword
- cognito-idp:AdminRespondToAuthChallenge
- cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth
- cognito-idp:ConfirmForgotPassword

Am I missing something here?

Comment: To verify this is indeed an IAM permssion problem, TEMPORARLY give full admin access persmission to your Lambda function and try again.  If it works, this is indeed an IAM policy missing.  Reading the error message will mostly provide you with the name of the API call which is missing from the permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we create a new App client, by default it has an associated App client secret.

I created one more app client, without "Client Secret". I used this new App client.

I modified the code to use the API AdminInitiateAuth, instead of the InitiateAuth

I was able to successfully login.

Here is the reference link, which was useful - [Amplify "Unable to verify secret hash for client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487433/amplify-unable-to-verify-secret-hash-for-client)